# How to add 2 TextView in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am new in android. I have to add 2 TextView in fragment. When I add 2 TextView then 2nd text message overrides the 1st text message. How can we avoid from overriding? My xml code is below

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.litifer.simple_demo_litifer.Fragment_One">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Save More on Flight Tickets!"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:textSize="25dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_below = "@+id/text1"
    android:text="Flat Rs.500 Cashback on domestic flight tickets. Use code:FLY500 and book now #PaytmKaro"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: use a `Linearlayout` with vertical `orientation`

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.litifer.simple_demo_litifer.Fragment_One">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Save More on Flight Tickets!"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:text="Flat Rs.500 Cashback on domestic flight tickets. Use code:FLY500 and book now #PaytmKaro" />
</LinearLayout>
```

From the Documentation:

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display
>   a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single
>   child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a
>   way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children
>   overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a
>   FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by
>   assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity
>   attribute.

i also encourage you to read the Developer [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#CommonLayouts)

Comment: I would suggest adding some further reading for the OP, as his understanding of Layouts is minimal. Explain why he should use a LinearLayout and what is going wrong for him with the FrameLayout. A solution is handy, but an explanation is better than just copying and pasting code.